# What are the benefits of MVC Web API over ASMX service in business sense and not as a developer?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASMX web service which is internally calling some Payment related APIs and is currently processing few thousand orders daily. We are planning to upgrade this wrapper service to Asp.Net Web APIs. How can I explain the business the benefits of this upgrade in a non technical way as they might not be able to understand the technical terms? Budget and resources is not an issue for this upgrade.

Comment: What are *your* reasons to upgrade this wrapper service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web API is better because it is based on HTTP and not SOAP. HTTP contains headers that give information on the content. It is more easier to understand and develop for. Since Web API is in HTTP it means that you are able to reach many more clients. The body of a http message can contain any kind of content.

From a business perspective it is easier to maintain, easier to develop and you are able to reach more clients. It also means that you are able to always extend functionality. With those qualities such as the maintainability and the ease of development means that it is ultimately cheaper and more effective.

In software whatever is easy to maintain and understand is the ultimate king from all angles (financial and technological).